# Install and gulp plugins

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, package.json

I have a little trouble while installing Gulp.

In my gulpfile.js I have these require:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var del = require('del');
var notify = require("gulp-notify");
var htmlExtended = require("gulp-html-extend");
var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
var pngquant = require('imagemin-pngquant');
var bower = require('gulp-bower');
```

And in my package I have my Dependencies:

```
{
  "name": "PROJECT",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.11.0",
    "del": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-bower": "^0.0.11",
    "gulp-html-extend": "^1.1.4",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^2.3.0",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "^1.0.0-rc.1",
    "gulp-notify": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.0.1",
    "imagemin-pngquant": "^4.2.0",
    "lodash": "^3.9.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "install": "bower install"
  }
}
```

The problem is when I start a `npm install` or `npm install --save-dev` it installs tons of plugins I didn't ask for. Here is my "node_modules" folder after the installation:

[Too many gulp plugins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXL7S.png)

How do I install *only* the plugins I asked for in my package.json?

Comment: Please consider marking your question answered or editing your question to get more information. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are running `npm` version 3. In version 3, npm changed to have all child dependencies in the top level folder under `node_modules`. In version 2, npm had a module's child dependencies in another `node_modules` folder.

To make sure you do not have unnecessary items in that folder, remove all folders within `node_modules` and run `npm install` again. This will flush out any folders that have not been added to package.json.

By the way, you can check your `npm` version with `npm -v` or `npm --version` while within your project folder.

Sample `npm` 2 folder structure:

```
README.md
node_modules/
    dependency_a/
        node_modules/
            dependency_of_a/
package.json
```

Sample `npm` 3 folder structure:

```
README.md
node_modules/
    dependency_a/
    dependency_of_a/
package.json
```